# Does the motion co-processor chip register if your iPhone hits the floor when lost?

Tags: iphone

I lost my iPhone 7i on the concrete floor. Is there a way to read out from the motion tracking a time stamp when this happened?

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not expose this data to users, so the answer is a general no.

Whether the data was captured doesn’t matter as much as observability does - similar to the “if a tree falls in a forest” thought experiment.

Comment: He's technically not asking if users can read it, just if it can be read. If Apple can read it then the answer would be yes. Have they been known to do this in warranty claims?

Comment: @Andreas This site is for user level details. If the OP is asking SDK or code questions it should be closed here as off topic and migrated to stack overflow. My answer is tailored for this site specifically despite the question being a little vague since the OP showed no research.

Comment: Whether Apple is known to access this data or not is pretty much user level knowledge. It would certainly be of interest to me if I were to open a warranty claim.

Comment: I am just interested out of technical standard, not warranty but It could help to document time and place for inpackt. Does the accelerator activate and written to any log base on the pick up of speed when phone is beaten out of my hand? There is a sudden different in elevation, 1 m + and step registration. If possible I understand that I have to hire someone to get the data or get in contact with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

The sensor data is not stored unless you happened to be running an app that specifically stored that data while you dropped it.

Comment: I have enabled motion tracking in setup so the Health app is recording steps etc ..

Comment: So the question is wheter the motion tracking sensor is differencing between steps (softer trigger) and hard hit on concrete? Probably not, each trigger is counted as one step? The case is a forensic matter ..

Comment: @kasperilaug If you have law enforcement involved, please have them contact Apple in order to determine if evidence can be extracted from the device. Apple may have other options than ordinary users.

Comment: Tnx that’s a good idea .. I’ll do, but as a Open Source guy I’ll try to find tech answers in geek areas .. any suggestions where to post?

Comment: Not really - there’s no raw data stored that is accessible to ordinary users, so there’s not much “geeks” would be able to do I guess?

Comment: I think the raw data taken from the health app is stored after being aggregated and averaged out. It may not show the precise time the phone dropped but may show a window of ~20min when the average distance was 0. Your best bet at recovering this data is use a different device and restore from your iCloud backup the. Backup that device onto your computer. Digital information is useful for private investigation however has a lot of laws & regulations to be classified as “evidence” in court. Ask a lawyer if it’s applicable. You then may have to hire digital forensics to extract the same data.